# How can I get the Linux 'info' command to use vi rather than emacs for the editor?

Tags: emacs, vi, editors, info

I already have EDITOR=vim in my environment.

Comment: How you open an editor from within ```info```? Or are you only looking for vi-like key bindings?. There is an option ```--vi-keys```

Answer (score 5):

There is the --vi-keys option to info which lets you use VI keystrokes.

There is this [viewing info documentation with vim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5267/viewing-info-documentation-with-vim) which mentions a Vinfo plugin.

There is this: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=21, but it's 12 years old and doesn't appear to be maintained.

Info was part of the EMACS plan to take over the world, and like all their evil (see what I did there) plans, it didn't work. (This paragraph was intended humorously.)

Comment: This and the post below are informative. I had assumed info was running under emacs because the banner gave me 'emacs:...' after several fruitless keystrokes. Going to look ino Vinfo. In fact I'd like both info and man to pop up gvim windows... My screens always look like an estate sale anyway.

Answer (score 4):

`info` doesn't use Emacs, it just has the same look-and-feel. You can't get it to look like `vi`, but you can use `vi`-style keybindings:

```
info --vi-keys
```