# How do I dump text from the GNU info reader?

Tags: gnu, info, dump

I would like to dump the text from a page of a tool's info documentation to a text file and read and edit it subsequently in Vim.

Does the GNU info reader permit dumping of its text, or is there an easy way to find the directory of its source text and render it (in case of markup tags)?

Comment: Is : `info coreutils > coreutils.out`  what you want ? Have a look at [viewing info documentation with vim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5267/viewing-info-documentation-with-vim) also.

Comment: To check the directory of its source text : `whereis info`. On my system they are located in `/usr/share/info`. A lot of commands are include in `coreutils`.